# how to use .css to add an address to the end of every .html page?

Tags: html, css

right now, all of my web pages have this at the end:

`<address>&copy; 2014-2016 My Brand. All rights reserved. | <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a> | <a href="Privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></address>`

As you might guess, I recently had to modify this from 2015 to 2016. I only have maybe 20 pages on my site, and they are all static .html pages, but it was a pain nonetheless.

I wanna do this with css instead. Is this possible?

What I'm guessing is to modify every page with a `<div id="endingaddress"></div>` at the end, and then in the css file I need to put something like:

`#endingaddress
{
  ...what goes here?
}`

How do I do it?

Comment: One option would be simply not to put the date. (You could even omit the copyright notice entirely. Copyright notices are optional and don't particularly affect your legal rights.)

Comment: i'd would have done this through the server code. say, had you worked with ASP.NET MVC you'd just put there @DateTime.Now so it would have changed according to the year instead of you having to change it every time, ever through css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` CSS property won't be interpreted : so you can't put text + `<a></a>` inside or `&copy` will be displayed as is.

So here what you have to do :

```css
#endingaddress::before {
  content : " © 2014-2016 My Brand. All rights reserved. |";
}
```

```html
<div id="endingaddress">
<a href="Contact.html">Contact</a> | <a href="Privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a>
</div>
```

Learn more about [`content`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp) property and [`::before`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) / `::after` CSS selectors.

Comment: This almost worked, except it did not put the line in the "address" with a dashed dotted line at the bottom of the page. So I encapsulated it between `<address>` tags and it worked except for one weird thing. The user can no longer highlight the address text between © and the first pipe (|) . But the user **can** highlight the link text for contact and privacy. There is always some little thing that goes odd, isn't there.

Comment: @DrZ214
I didn't know about that. Yes it's very strange, all the code (content) added by CSS before is not highlightable. Now that I checked I can't find any exemple who is hilightable and it seem's there is no attribute to make it.
I think it's the price to pay.

Comment: That is so weird. I confirmed this in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE it lets you highlight it **only** if you select a block of text bigger than it. So based on that we can't even tell if it's following some rule set forth in HTML5, or if it's just a glitch of oversight. But don't worry tho, I don't really need it highlightable for my site.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-element

```css
#endingaddress::after {
  content : "Copyright © 2016"
}
```

```html
<div id="endingaddress"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

dave's answer is good, but if you don't want to change the year every time by yourself, you can do it like this:

css:

```
#endingaddress::after {
   content : "©  " attr(data-date) " Copyright message";
}
```

in js:

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
document.querySelector("#endingaddress").setAttribute("data-date",year);
```

Comment: And if the user's clock is all messed up? Copyright 2014-2009!

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 well, as i wrote as a comment to the question, you can always do this on the server, so the clock is your own.